# Android change the Edit text value when enter the other Edit text Value

Tags: java, android

I have enter the date from DatePicker in 1st EditText but but it get only current date , when i select the date from date picker in 1st EditText and when i insert the any int value in 2nd Edit text it will gate change the date in 3rd Edit Text. So how can do this I m trying since 5 hours but can't get proper solution.Can someone help me please. Thanks to appreciate.

For example:

1. I enter the Date in = 1st Edittext 15 sept 2014
2. I enter the 5 digit in = 2nd Edit text
3. The date should be display in 3rd Edit Text like 20 sept 2014.

Here is my Activity code .

```
// Get current date by calender
 final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


etReplacementDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
         .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
         .append(" "));


 etReplacementDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        showDialog(DATE_OF_REPLACEMENT);
    }
});


 String fixedDate = etReplacementDate.getText().toString().trim();

 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
 convertedDate = new Date();
try
{
    convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(fixedDate);
}
catch (ParseException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Date convertedDate  = " + convertedDate);
String intervalDays = etInterval_Days.getText().toString().trim();

  if(intervalDays.trim().length()>0){

      try
      { 
          intConvertDays =Integer.parseInt(intervalDays);
      }
      catch(NumberFormatException ne){
         System.out.println("could not parse :: " +ne);
       }

   }

   System.out.println("strConvertDays in afterTextChanged: " + intConvertDays);


    etInterval_Days.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String intervalDays = etInterval_Days.getText().toString().trim();

              if(intervalDays.trim().length()>0){

                  try
                  { 
                      intConvertDays =Integer.parseInt(intervalDays);
                  }
                  catch(NumberFormatException ne){
                     System.out.println("could not parse :: " +ne);
                   }

               }

            cal2.setTime(convertedDate);
            cal2.add(Calendar.MONTH, intConvertDays);
            Date resultDate = cal2.getTime(); 
            String strResultDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(resultDate);
            System.out.println("After one days strResultDate : " + strResultDate);

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDate =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String strConverted_Date = simpleDate.format(resultDate);
            etNextReplanishmentDate.setText(strConverted_Date);

            cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);
            Date beforDate = cal2.getTime();
            String beforDate_String = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(beforDate);
            System.out.println("beforDate_String: " + beforDate_String);

        }
    });


}


@Override 
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id) 
    {
    case DATE_OF_REPLACEMENT:return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListenerReplacement, year, month, day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListenerReplacement = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

// when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
        int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

    year  = selectedYear;
    month = selectedMonth;
    day   = selectedDay;

    // Show selected date 
    etReplacementDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
            .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
            .append(" "));



    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this -

```
String finalDate = day + " " + month + " " + year; 

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

try {
    c.setTime(sdf.parse(finalDate));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

int addDays = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());

c.add(Calendar.DATE, addDays);  // number of days to add
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
String output = sdf1.format(c.getTime());
```

To automatically change date in editText3, you can use TextWatcher -

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //get values in editText1 and 2 and add them

int val1 = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
int val2 = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());

//add the above code here

String finalDate = day + " " + month + " " + year; 

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

try {
    c.setTime(sdf.parse(finalDate));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String addDays = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());

c.add(Calendar.DATE, addDays);  // number of days to add
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
String output = sdf1.format(c.getTime());

    editText3.setText(output + "");


        }
    };
```